# How to find an equation composed of nothing but integers and of as few digits as possible which equals a specific integer?

Tags: arithmetic, computational-mathematics

Say I have an integer *A*, and *A* has *n* digits. Say I want want to find an equation which contains as **few digits** as possible which results in *A*. Is there a straightforward repeatable way of doing this? Even finding a consistent way of finding very **few** digits (though maybe not **fewest**) would be great for now!

Example: 123 = 2^7 - 5, which only takes 3 digits (2, 7 and 5).

One idea is to just observe what grows fastest, and from my very little mathematical experience, exponents fit the bill. That way, if we have a massive number *A* with billions of digits, the exponent's fast growth means that we could use fewer digits to accomplish this, than say, simply adding numbers or multiplying them.

Now in reality, I would also like to minimize the number of operations, but this may make the problem much harder, so we can ignore that for now.

Comment: ", if we have a massive number A with billions of digits, the exponent's fast growth means that we could use as little as 3 digits to accomplish this. Say for instance 1'000'000'000 can be written as 10 ^ 9."  1,000,000,000 doesn't have billions of digits, so you may want to amend this sentence. In terms of minimising the number of operations- that's probably a (very) difficult problem to solve. I'm not sure what use there is for it. Anyhow, good luck!